# How to view all post installed packages in terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Can Somebody tell me how to just view the post-installed packages in terminal (Ubuntu 18.04), instead of showing whole list of packages?

I had already tried `gunzip -c /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | grep 'apt-get install' | cut -f4- -d" " | tr ' ' $'\n' | sort -u`

Comment: You already tried that^ command, and got what results that were not satisfying in what way?

Comment: try `dpkg -l | grep ii` which will list all installed packages.

Comment: You can use `sudo apt list --installed`.